# Custom Log Layout - Log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

In log4j I customize my logs by extending the log4j Layout class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class CustomLayout extends Layout{

    public String format(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
        return "any log"
    }
}
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=com.sample.CustomLayout
```

How do I create a customized layout in log4j2?

Comment: What kind of customization are you interested ?

Comment: I have the need to customize all log lines to an internally defined pattern.
Ex: #prefix# any log ...

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code for existing layouts to see what they're doing?

Comment: Have you found a solution by now? Having the same issue here...